# extend from parent in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is My Main Vuex Config

```
    export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        customer // imported at top of store.js
    }
});
```

This is My Customer Module

```
export const customer = {
        namespaced: true,
        state: {
            customer: {
                status: {},
                contacts: [],
                users: [],
                tags: [],
                comments: [],
                reminders: [],
                timeline: [],
            },
        },
        modules: {
            tags
        }
    };
```

This is My Nested Tag Module

```
export const tags = {
        namespaced: true,
        state: {
            tags: []
        },
    };
```

Now here is my question. i want tag Module extend tag state from his parent which in located in state of customer.
how can i do that?

Comment: Anyone knows anything???

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html